# as3 print a page with text, image and data grid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have an AIR application.
I want to print a set of text, image and datagrid my document is like a report.
As datagrid has different heights, I don't know how to do.
Could you help me ?
Best regards

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example from the docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/printing/FlexPrintJob.html

FormPrintFooter.mxml

```
<s:VGroup name="FormPrintFooter"
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        width="60%"
        horizontalAlign="right" >

    <!-- Declare and initialize the product total variable. -->
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var pTotal:Number = 0;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label text="Product Total: {pTotal}"/>

</s:VGroup>
```

FormPrintView.mxml

```
<!-- Custom control to print the Halo DataGrid control on multiple pages. -->
<s:VGroup name="FormPrintView"
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        xmlns="*">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.*;

            // Declare and initialize the variables used in the component.
            // The application sets the actual prodTotal value.
            [Bindable]
            public var pageNumber:Number = 1;

            [Bindable]
            public var prodTotal:Number = 0;

            // Control the page contents by selectively hiding the header and
            // footer based on the page type.
            public function showPage(pageType:String):void {
                if (pageType == "first" || pageType == "middle") {
                    // Hide the footer.
                    footer.includeInLayout = false;
                    footer.visible = false;
                }
                if (pageType == "middle" || pageType == "last") {
                    // The header won't be used again; hide it.
                    header.includeInLayout = false;
                    header.visible = false;
                }
                if (pageType == "last") {
                    // Show the footer.
                    footer.includeInLayout = true;
                    footer.visible = true;
                }
                //Update the DataGrid layout to reflect the results.
                validateNow();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- The template for the printed page, with the contents for all pages. -->
    <s:VGroup width="80%" horizontalAlign="left">
        <s:Label text="Page {pageNumber}"/>
    </s:VGroup>

    <FormPrintHeader id="header" />

    <!-- The data grid. The sizeToPage property is true by default, so the last
        page has only as many grid rows as are needed for the data. -->
    <mx:PrintDataGrid id="myDataGrid" width="60%" height="100%">
        <!-- Specify the columns to ensure that their order is correct. -->
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Index" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Qty" />
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:PrintDataGrid>

    <!-- Create a FormPrintFooter control and set its prodTotal variable. -->
    <FormPrintFooter id="footer" pTotal="{prodTotal}" />

</s:VGroup>
```

PrintDataGridExample.mxml

```
<!-- Main application to print a Halo DataGrid control on multiple pages. -->
<s:Application name="PrintDataGridExample.mxml"
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        initialize="initData();">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        import mx.printing.*;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import FormPrintView;
        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;

        // Declare variables and initialize simple variables.
        [Bindable]
        public var dgProvider:ArrayCollection;
        public var footerHeight:Number = 20;
        public var prodIndex:Number;
        public var prodTotal:Number = 0;

        // Data initialization.
        public function initData():void {
            // Create the data provider for the DataGrid control.
            dgProvider = new ArrayCollection;
        }

        // Fill the dgProvider ArrayCollection with the specified items.
        public function setdgProvider(items:int):void {
            prodIndex=1;
            dgProvider.removeAll();
            for (var z:int=0; z<items; z++) {
                var prod1:Object = {};
                prod1.Qty = prodIndex * 7;
                prod1.Index = prodIndex++;
                prodTotal += prod1.Qty;
                dgProvider.addItem(prod1);
            }
        }

        // The function to print the output.
        public function doPrint():void {
            var printJob:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();
            if (printJob.start()) {
                // Create a FormPrintView control as a child of the current view.
                var thePrintView:FormPrintView = new FormPrintView();
                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addElement(thePrintView);

                //Set the print view properties.
                thePrintView.width=printJob.pageWidth;
                thePrintView.height=printJob.pageHeight;
                thePrintView.prodTotal = prodTotal;
                // Set the data provider of the FormPrintView component's data grid
                // to be the data provider of the displayed data grid.
                thePrintView.myDataGrid.dataProvider = myDataGrid.dataProvider;
                // Create a single-page image.
                thePrintView.showPage("single");
                // If the print image's data grid can hold all the provider's rows,
                // add the page to the print job.
                if (!thePrintView.myDataGrid.validNextPage)  {
                    printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
                }
                // Otherwise, the job requires multiple pages.
                else {
                    // Create the first page and add it to the print job.
                    thePrintView.showPage("first");
                    printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
                    thePrintView.pageNumber++;
                    // Loop through the following code until all pages are queued.
                    while (true) {
                        // Move the next page of data to the top of the print grid.
                        thePrintView.myDataGrid.nextPage();
                        thePrintView.showPage("last");
                        // If the page holds the remaining data, or if the last page
                        // was completely filled by the last grid data, queue it for printing.
                        // Test if there is data for another PrintDataGrid page.
                        if (!thePrintView.myDataGrid.validNextPage) {
                            // This is the last page; queue it and exit the print loop.
                            printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
                            break;
                        } else {
                            // This is not the last page. Queue a middle page.
                            thePrintView.showPage("middle");
                            printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
                            thePrintView.pageNumber++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // All pages are queued; remove the FormPrintView control to free memory.
                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.removeElement(thePrintView);
            }
            // Send the job to the printer.
            printJob.send();
        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Panel title="DataGrid Printing Example"
            width="75%" height="75%"
            horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:VGroup left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
            <mx:DataGrid id="myDataGrid" dataProvider="{dgProvider}">
                <mx:columns>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Index"/>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Qty"/>
                </mx:columns>
            </mx:DataGrid>

            <s:Label width="100%" color="blue"
                text="Specify the number of lines and click Fill Grid first. Then you can click Print."/>

            <s:TextInput id="dataItems" text="35"/>

            <s:HGroup>
                <s:Button id="setDP" label="Fill Grid" click="setdgProvider(int(dataItems.text));"/>
                <s:Button id="printDG" label="Print" click="doPrint();"/>
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Panel>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but how to do if I want to print a label, a datagrid, another label, another datagrid etc... Best regards